# How to hide PhoneGap Android SplashScreen?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have done simple app to get coordinates it is working fine but I have one issue while starting up the application one blank blank screen is coming before firing index.html . How can I remove that blank black screen while starting my app. I am using cordova-2.4.0.js

My index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
      // cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", []);
      navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }

    </script>

    <style>
    h3 {
    left: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 60%;
    width: 100%;
    }
    body
    {
    background-color:#D7EBFF;
    }
    header
    {
    background-color:#C3E1FF;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function showLocation(position)
         {
          var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
          var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Latitude : " + latitude + "</br> Longitude: " + longitude ;
          //alert("Latitude : " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude);
         }

        function errorHandler(err)
         {
          if(err.code == 1)
           {
            alert("Error: Access is denied!");
           }
          else if( err.code == 2)
          {
            alert("Error: Position is unavailable!");
           }
        }
        function getLocation()
        {

          var watchID = null;
          if(navigator.geolocation)
           {
              var options = { timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true };
              watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options);
           }
           else
           {
              alert("Sorry, does not support geolocation!");
           }
        }

        </script>
  </head>

        <body onload="getLocation();">
        <header>
        <center>
        <h2>Gps Coordinates </h2>
        </center>
        </header>
         <h3>
             <p id="demo">Searching for GPS..</p>

         </h3>
        </body>
  </html>
```

And my MainActivity.java class is

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/WWW/index.html");
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already tried to remove that blank screen while the index.html loading but i didn't find how. I guess it's because the device is loading the app.

What you can do is create your own splash screen instead ? 
By following this link you'll find how to create your own splash screen: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html

Hope that could help you.

Comment: Yeah Thanks for replay. But How can I copy splash screen image into the res/drawable directories of my Android project. How can I get those images? Need to take screen shoots? else any Alternative way ?

Comment: You can just add images from your documents to the res/drawable directories. You can create your own splash screen with photoshop, gimp... It's a simple image, call it splash.png and set the different size, then copy them into the right directories :  (xhdpi) : 960x720
(hdpi) : 640 x 480
(mdpi) : 470 x 320
(ldpi) : 426 x 320

Comment: Thank you stephen. Will try your suggestion.